# many-to-many relationship OrderBy - Laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, many-to-many, sql-order-by

[image]

**I am trying to order products** by thp price in options table 
the price can be in multi currency for that i add  **dolor_price** calculated as code below.
but the result was the following Error 
*SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 **Unknown column** 'options.dolor_price' in 'order clause'*

```
    $products=Product::with(["options"=> function($option){
        $option->where('name' ,'unique name' );

        $option->selectSub(function ($q) {
            $rateEruToDolor =2;
            $rateAedToDolor =3;
            $q->selectRaw(' IF(currency=0,price * ?, IF(currency=1,price * ?, price))',
            [$rateEruToDolor,$rateAedToDolor]);
        }, 'dolor_price');
    }]);
    $products->orderBy('options.dolor_price');
    dd($products->get()->toArray());
```

Comment: use `$products->orderBy('dolor_price');` instead

Comment: same error
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dolor_price' in 'order clause'

Comment: use `join` instead of `with`, or apply `orderBy` after `get`

Comment: since `with` always run 2 queries use `$option->orderBy('dolor_price')` or
`$products->get()->sortBy('options.dolor_price')`

Comment: may be the best solution to use ** join **  but can i cast the result to Product model again
because i use Product's methods in Views

Comment: I use pagination so i can not use "orderBy after get"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$rateEruToDolor =2;
$rateAedToDolor =3;
$products = Product::join('product_options', 'products.id', '=', 'product_options.product_id')
      ->join('options', 'product_options.option_id', '=', 'options.id')
      ->selectRaw('price, currency, IF(currency=0, price * ?, IF(currency=1, price * ?, price)) 
                   as dolor_price', [$rateEruToDolor, $rateAedToDolor]);
$products->orderBy('dolor_price');
dd($products->get()->toArray());
```

List all of the fields in your products/options table along with `price` and `currency` already listed in the `selectRaw('xxx, xxx, price, currency, IF ...)` method above.
Hope this helps